# How to stop tracking/mapping between variables in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an EF Code First table that contains data I do not ever want to change, but I want to retrieve the data to a couple of variables that are independent of each other. The problem is that making a change to either variable changes the values of the other one.

For example, the EF Code First context is defined:

```
public class MyVal {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public double SomeVal { get; set; }
}
```

After populating the table with data:

```
context.MyVals.AddOrUpdate(new MyVal { SomeVal = 1 });
context.MyVals.AddOrUpdate(new MyVal { SomeVal = 2 });
context.MyVals.AddOrUpdate(new MyVal { SomeVal = 3 });
```

Next, I perform a query:

```
List<MyVal> myvals = _context.MyVals.AsNoTracking().Where(d => d.SomeVal >= 0).Select(m => m).ToList();
```

The above query returns the expected data. As you can see, I've specified AsNoTracking(). Next I want to create another var that I will modify:

```
List<MyVal> myvals1 = myvals;
```

And now I want to modify myvals1 WITHOUT effecting any values in myvals:

```
foreach (MyVal m in myvals1) {
    m.SomeVal = m.SomeVal * 2;
}
```

myvals1 will now contain 3 records with these values:

```
2
4
6
```

The problem is that myvals also gets changed to:

```
2
4
6
```

Since I used AsNoTracking() when I queried the context, what else do I need to do to make these variables independent of each other? Why are these variables seemingly treated as the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that you are not creating a new object by simply assigning to a variable, as object int c# are passed by reference, not by a value. So when you are assigning `myvals` to `myvals1` you simply pass a reference to the same object. So you need to create a new `List` and work with it:

```
List<MyVal> myvals1 = new List<MyVal>(myvals);
```

If you need to create an object of `MyVal` from another object there are multiple solutions like implementing `IClonable` interface, creating a `Clone` method (the simple implementation won't work for nested complex objects, to do this check this question: [Deep cloning objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects)), using an `AutoMapper` library.

Here's an example of creating a `Clone` method:

```
public class MyVal 
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public double SomeVal { get; set; }

    public MyVal Clone(MyVal obj)
    {
        return new MyVal {id = obj.id, SomeVal = obj.SomeVal }
    }
}
```

Comment: Very simple solution. I did not realize I was passing a reference to the vars. This makes sense... I'm sure your answer is correct, but I want to change my code and see that this solves the problem. I will mark your answer after I make sure this is the cause of my problem. Thank you!

Comment: what if I need to create an individual `MyVal`? I tried `MyVal myval = new MyVal(m)` but I get an error saying MyVal does not contain a constructor that takes 1 argument. Do I need to modify the MyVal class or am I trying to create `myval` incorrectly?